# Free C/C++ and Java implementations of PPP?

Tags: java, c, ppp

Are there free C/C++ and Java implementations of the point-to-point protocol (PPP) for use over a serial line? The C/C++ implementation will go into embedded hardware so portability is a concern. I'm not looking for a full TCP/IP stack, just something to provide a connection-oriented base to build on top of.

Comment: did you try googling for "ppp open source"?

Comment: Google seems to be a magical beast. Your search terms brought up better results than my own. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one used in most Linux-based systems is in C and is named [Paul's PPP Package](http://ppp.samba.org/).

FreeBSD has a completely different one, also written in C, but I have no experience with it.

Comment: This looks great. Thanks! The only snag is that every source file has its own license (no joke) so I'll have to go one by one to figure out what licensing I am obligating myself to.

Answer (score 1):

In linux I use chat and pppd for using ppp over serial line in linux. ( Adding a gprs modem to get internet connection )

Answer (score 1):

I found a library named TINI that includes a ppp java implementation
http://raud.ut.ee/~tec/static/api/tini1.15/javadocs/firmware/index.html

And more description here
http://www.maxim-ic.com/products/ibutton/software/1wire/1wire_api.cfm

Hope it helps

Comment: If I understand http://www.maxim-ic.com/products/tini/software/soft_order.cfm correctly, TINI may only be used if you purchase hardware from the parent company (Dallas). In short, I don't think I can use this software library.